# Why can't I use the Constraint kind in type family declarations?

Tags: haskell, types, constraints, type-families

I'm using

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, ConstraintKinds, ExistentialQuantification #-}
```

and have typed the following code:

```
class NoConstraint x where {}
instance forall x. NoConstraint x where {}

type family Classes (c :: [* -> Constraint]) (x :: *) :: Constraint
type instance Classes [] x = NoConstraint x
type instance Classes (h : t) x = (h x, Classes t x)
```

However, GHC(i) rejects this with:

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class `Constraint'
```

It seems to be, however, that this should be completely possible.

---

Edit: I've now found out that there are also other problems with the above code.
However, this remains a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because `Constraint` is not exported by default from `Prelude`. You can hoogle `Constraint` to find where it is:

- https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Constraint

Try adding the following to your module:

```
import Data.Kind (Constraint)
```

It solves the problem for me.